# Column data returning in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using below query :

```
    select i.name as 'index name',c.name as 'column' from sys.indexes i 
    join  sys.columns c  on i.object_id = c.object_id;
```

the query is returning me data like :

```
    clst    bitpos
    clst    cid
    clst    colguid
    clust   cmprlevel
    clust   fgidfs
    clust   fillfact
```

However, I want to see my data like:

```
  clst  bitpos, cid,    colguid
  clust cmprlevel,  fgidfs  fillfact
```

I tried with distinct and group by like this. But it's not working:

```
    select distinct(i.name) as 'index name',c.name as 'column' from s 
   ys.indexes i join  sys.columns c  on i.object_id = c.object_id group by i.name;
```

Could any one please help with this. I'm using mssql

Comment: Hi Shiwangini, your required output can be achieved by following query-
SELECT     a.name As index_name, column_name = replace
                          ((SELECT c.name  AS [data()]
                              from sys.indexes i 
      join  sys.columns c  on i.object_id = c.object_id
                              WHERE  i.name = a.name
                              ORDER BY i.name FOR xml path('')), ' ', ', ')
FROM         sys.indexes a
WHERE     a.name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  a.name

Comment: @Dev , your query is helpful. Thanks